# Android: pass lambda to recycler adapter by android data binding

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I am using mvvm and data binding on my project.I have a recycler view and make an adapter.my data shown in recycler view fine.Now i want to create item click listener.

So at the end of my adapter i create an interface like this:

```
interface MyClickListener {
    void onItemClick(MyEntity myEntity);
}
```

after that i added this listener to constructor of my adapter:

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends ListAdapter<MyEntity, MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public MyClickListener clickListener;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(MyClickListener clickListener) {
        super(MyEntity.DIFF_CALLBACK);
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    } 

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyEntity item = getItem(position);
    holder.bind(item,clickListener);
}
```

and i send my callback to bind view xml :

```
private void bind(MyEntity item, MyClickListener clickListener) {
    binding.setEntity(item);
    binding.setClickListener(clickListener);
    binding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

In xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="entity"
            type="com.test.database.myEntity" />
        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="com.test.home.MyClickListener" />
    </data>


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview_id"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:onClick="@{() -> clickListener.onItemClick(entity)}">
```

and i initialize this callback in my adapter:

```
MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(myEntity -> {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), myEntity.getID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

But when i run application i got this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol class MyClickListener
```

What is my mistake?

I have to make class instead of interface and make a new object? There is no way to use interface ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data Binding onClick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51418468/data-binding-onclick-not-working)

Comment: I changed xml onClick to `(v) -> clickListener.onItemClick(batman)` but error happen in compile time because it can not find `MyClickListener` @faranjit

Comment: In general way i have to create a class with a method inside it and then pass object of class inside xml but i do not want to create a class and why i can not create on the fly callback and do my clicked?

Comment: Whats happen if instead of class object you use a companion object?

Comment: I am using java so i cannot use `companion ` @Dak28

Comment: Well yhe sorry, static class then, im so use to speak and public code with kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue related to access modifier of your `interface`. Try to change it `public`

```
public interface MyClickListener {
    void onItemClick(MyEntity myEntity);
}
```